# Get ID by username (Roblox)

Tags: javascript, html, api, roblox

I would like to know how I can send a request via [ROBLOX's User API](https://users.roblox.com/docs) but it seems that is not specifically documented.
I am making a log in site via status and I need the ID to get the users status. I appreciate any help given.

---

If I ***absolutely*** need to use `/v1/user/search`, I want to  get the id of the first user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to simply make a fetch request and get the User ID from the URL.

```
function getUserID(name)
{
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        fetch(`https://www.roblox.com/users/profile?username=${name}`)
            .then(r => {
                // check to see if URL is invalid.
                if (!r.ok) { throw "Invalid response"; }
                // return the only digits in the URL "the User ID"
                return r.url.match(/\d+/)[0];
            })
            .then(id =>{
                // this is where you get your ID
                console.log(id);
            })
    })
}

// without Promise

function getUserID(name)
{
    fetch(`https://www.roblox.com/users/profile?username=${name}`)
        .then(r => {
            if (!r.ok) { throw "Invalid response"; }
            return r.url.match(/\d+/)[0];
        })
        .then(id => {
            console.log(id);
        })
}
```

Sorry I'm new to posting answers on StackOverflow. If you need any help feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Just send a get request to `https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=UserName` its pretty simple, if you want in js here.

````
var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://api.roblox.com/users/get-by-username?username=xLeki", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Players:GetUserIdFromNameAsync()`](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Players/GetUserIdFromNameAsync) or this [DevForm link I found](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/getting-userid-from-username/538041)

These might be incorrect because Game sites are blocked for me :(

Comment: I am not looking for lua, but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To get the user name you can use `https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/<USER ID>`, while getting the status of a user you need `https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/<USER ID>/status`.

Answer (score 0):

import requests
import json

def get_user_id(username):

```
url = 'https://users.roblox.com/v1/usernames/users'

# Request body as a JSON string
request_body = {
    'usernames': [username],
    'excludeBannedUsers': True
}
json_data = json.dumps(request_body)


headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json_data)


user_data = json.loads(response.text)
if len(user_data['data']) > 0:
    user_id = user_data['data'][0]['id']
    return user_id
else:
    return None
```

username = 'lilboii36'
user_id = get_user_id(username)
if user_id:
print(f"User ID for {username}: {user_id}")
else:
print(f"No user found with username {username}")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).